# Assign several classes to an element with acf checkboxes in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, class, checkbox, custom-post-type

I've created a custom field with the "Advanced Custom Field (acf)" plugin for wordpress.
In this custom field, I have got a checbox field type with several checkboxes for multiple custom post type.

I would like that when I checked some checkboxes, these are becoming classes for my custom post type.

Currently, it works when I only have one class, but when I check several checkboxes and want to have multiple classes, it doesn't work anymore, there is a "," between my 2 classes in the html and I can only target the last class.

Here is my code line at the moment

```
<li class="<?php echo the_field('checkbox') ?> ">
```

How could I remove this "," between the 2 classes?

Thanks you very for the help, I'd appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$checkboxvalue = get_field('checkbox'); 

foreach($checkboxvalue as $key => $check){ 
    $classnames .= $check.' '; //$classnames will store class1 class2 class3
};

?>
<li class="<?php echo $classnames; ?> ">
```

So, that way your li will have multiple classes. I hope it will help you :)

Comment: I thought it will work but unfortunately not :( In fact, only "the_field" returns the fields in my class. I can't try with "get_field" because it shows me "array" in the class.

btw thanks for your answer

Comment: Ok I solved it,

instead of "the_field" I put "get_field" and it wasn't necessary to add the "str_replace".
I add the following code



    $checkboxvalue = get_field('checkbox');
       foreach($checkboxvalue as $key => $check){
        echo $check.' ';
       };

Comment: Ok Moreno,i revised the answer, so it will help to other users :)